# input box line-height issue in chrome?

Tags: html, css

I set `height:40px` and `line-height:40px` to a input field. It working in all browsers except chrome.

IE7 and IE8 not working properly with out line-height property. So I set this property.

Refer below image.

[image]

HTML:

```html
Login :
<input type="text" class="inputtxt" />
```

CSS:

```css
.inputtxt {
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

in Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8DF7G/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest use padding instead of line-height.

```
input {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    padding:10px 5px;
}
```

Comment: This won't work in IE8.  You'll need to use: `-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; ` as well

Comment: @davidpauljunior box-sizing needed when you want padding within height. But this is not the case here. expected height is 40, given height 20+20 padding will make it to 40;

Comment: You're right!  I was accidentally testing with an `input type="search"` instead of `type="text"` and it's all different.  Height declaration needs removing and box-sizing adding to fix width, not height.  Very strange.

Comment: This isnt a solution for multi-line `textarea`s